# Execute 'then' in 'fetch' only if a condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I have an api returning bytearray, using saveAs for saving the bytearray to pdf. The following is sample code. My requirement is, can I do away with two thens ? I tried putting the saveascode in first then, even though a pdf is downloaded, it is not able to load.

I have some headers, which I can check in first then.
`response.headers.get("status"));`
Only if the status is ok, I need to execute the second then. 
is it possible ?
As of now,  even if `response.ok` is not true, the second then is executed.  Any thoughts ?

```
fetch(param).then(function(response) {
  if (response.headers.get("status")) == 'ok') {
  return response.blob();
}

}).then(function(response) {
      if (response == undefined) {
        //handle
      } else {
        const file = new Blob([response], {
          type: 'application/pdf',
        });
        saveAs(file, fileName);
      }
```

Comment: You will need two because `response.blob()` returns a promise as well.

Comment: You can wrap `fetch` into your own layer though

Comment: ok, but if status is not ok, then can the code be changed so that second then is not executed ?

Comment: you can throw in case when status is not "ok", then you can add catch after second then

Comment: Here is the code  fetch(param)
.then(function(response) {
  if (response.headers.get("status")) != 'ok') {
    throw new Error('not OK')
  }
  return response.blob();
})
.then(function(response) {
      if (response == undefined) {
        //handle
      } else {
        const file = new Blob([response], {
          type: 'application/pdf',
        });
        saveAs(file, fileName);
      })
.catch(e) {}

Comment: then will always be executed unless you run into an error

Comment: No, it is not just some unknown error, it is an error that we throw by hand if the status is not equal 'ok'.  Thus we force skipping two then blocks and end up inside catch block. If the status equals 'ok' then no error is thrown and the execution control happily goes to the next then block. So, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should put your `then` handler inside that `if` block if you only want to execute it conditionally:

```
fetch(param).then(function(response) {
  if (response.headers.get("status")) == 'ok') {
    return response.blob().then(function(response) {
      const file = new Blob([response], {
        type: 'application/pdf',
      });
      saveAs(file, fileName);
    }
  } else {
    // handle
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch(param).then(function (response) {
    if (response.headers.get("status") == 'ok') {
        return response.blob();
    }
    else { throw new Error("Status is not ok"); }
}).then(function (response) {
    if (response == undefined) {
        //handle
    } else {
        const file = new Blob([response], {
            type: 'application/pdf',
        });
        saveAs(file, fileName);
    }
}, function (statusNotOKError) {
    //do handling if needed
});
```